# Windows Updates causes server to crash

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update, server-crashes

The last two times I've installed Windows Updates (security patches only) on our W2K03 file/print server, upon reboot, it has resulted in the OS crashing at the point where during logon the status banner reads 'applying computer settings'. This will result in an endless loop as it then reboots again, and the same thing happens.

Both times, the only fix has been to remove the recently installed updates through Safe Mode. Event Viewer did not reveal anything instructive. We're planning on replacing this server next year, so my plan is to simply not install any further updates. I would prefer to determine the problem, of course but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

[Set your server to do some sort of dump](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254649).

[Use `windbg` to read and diagnose the problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263).

Comment: OK, I will give this a try. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe process monitor from Sysinternals now supports startup logging if you configure it to do so. That may give you some hints as to what to look for.

You said that the logs didn't show anything instructive, did it show anything at all?

Comment: Under both system and application logs, I'm not seeing anything out of the ordinary.